# Assigning Row_Ids to dynamically added rows in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jeditable

I am working on making an editable `Datatable` using `Jeditable`. I need to be able to dynamically add rows, which I have successfully done. By default, it appears that `Datatables` will add everything with a `row_id` of `0`, which makes it impossible to differentiate added rows from each other.

So I am working on a function that assigns the `row_id`. There are no errors, but it also does not seem to work as it still returns a `row_id` of `0` for all added rows.

```
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
        var rowIndex = $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData([ "column1Data", "column2Data"]);
        var row = $('#example').dataTable().fnGetNodes(rowIndex);
    $(row).attr('id', row_id_counter);
    row_id_counter ++;
```

Entire code:

http://jsfiddle.net/j2frzerj/

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in the fiddle provided, and it is adding new table rows with sequential id's, starting with index 0. I am not seeing any duplicate id's of 0?

http://prntscr.com/ew3tg9

http://prntscr.com/ew3tlr

Comment: You're right! It does seem to be working properly. That means that while it is assigning correctly, the `POST` request must be wrong as my `row_id` value is always `0`. That value comes from `"row_id":oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[1]`. Is that not pulling the `id` from the `<TR>` tag?